# Jreport JasperRunManager.runReportToPdfStream null pointer exception

Tags: nullpointerexception, jasper-reports

i'm trying to get a PDF report using Jasper in my Java web application but i'm facing to an null pointer exception and i'm not able to find which is the error.

here below my code :

```
private void caricaReport() {
   try{
        InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream("reports/miooperearte.jasper");


        File OutDir = new File(outputDir);


         File outDir = new File(outputDir);
         outDir.mkdirs();
         OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(new File(outDir, "testReportNadia.pdf"));

         HashMap parameterMap = new HashMap();
         parameterMap.put("immagini_base_dir", "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Dboperearte/app/webroot/images/");


         Collection data = leggiOpere();

         JRBeanCollectionDataSource dataSource = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(data,false);

           JasperRunManager.runReportToPdfStream(is, os, parameterMap, dataSource);

    }
    catch (Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

variables "is", "os", "parameterMap" and "dataSource" are all filled, exception doesn't show which is the null problem only say null pointer exception...

any idea which can help me to solve or find the problem ?

Thanks

Comment: the stacktrace of the exception should tell you which line the problem is on. also you should try to use the debugger to step through your code and check each variable to see its value.

Comment: this is the problem ... stacktrace doesn't show anything :( .. and in debug last line running is JasperRunManager.runReportToPdfStream(is, os, parameterMap, dataSource); after that go in exception but all variable are filled correctly

Comment: Print your sent instances of data collection populated in report. if any field will null it will show null pointer exception.

Comment: @NadiaUI You must show stacktrace. Can you find it on application log? Can you write stacktrace to log and show it?

Comment: finally find which was the problem : wrong Jreport version in dependency ... i was getting crazy thanks (btw stacktrace showed a generic error during Jreport generation )

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that the `parameterMap` doesn't contain an entry for something that the JasperRunManager is expecting - make sure you aren't missing any values from there.